# Active record - Add reference to existing join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, rails-activerecord

The problem is : some "**PointOfInterest**" have some "**Category**" so it's a N-N relationship (i have a table with **pointID** and **categoryID**)
Now i have to add a new model named "**Itinerary**" and i want to use the same join table that i used between PointOfInterest and Category, it's possible? and how i can do it?

here **the code** of the migration for the relation between PointOfInterest and Category :

```
class CreatePointOfInterestPointOfInterestJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :point_of_interest_categories_point_of_interests, id: false do |t|
    t.integer :point_of_interest_id
    t.integer :point_of_interest_category_id
  end

  add_index :point_of_interest_categories_point_of_interests, :point_of_interest_category_id, name: 'poi_category'
  add_index :point_of_interest_categories_point_of_interests, :point_of_interest_id, name: 'poi'

  end
end
```

p.s: sorry for my English :)

Comment: Add new migration with: 
```add_reference :point_of_interest_categories_point_of_interests, :itineraries, foreign_key: true```

Comment: but in this way it add a new column to the join table, right?  i'd like to use the existing field named "point_of_interest_id", its' possibile?

Comment: @Leonardo but if you reuse the `point_of_interest_id` field for storing an `itinerary_id`, wouldn't that mean a given `point_of_interest_categories_point_of_interests` row could be for either an `Intinerary` or `PointOfInterest` and you wouldn't be able to tell the difference?